# Apache POI Cannot get a numeric value from a error formula cell

Tags: grails, apache-poi

im using apache POI and i have troubles on retrieving value for cell consist of formulas. you cant use get cell because it will retrieve the formula (eg, M21-K21, M21-K21L20) so i used getNumericCellValue(). it was working perfectly until i experienced the Err:522 value. it happens when the formula is invalid, maybe 1 of the column cannot be used for addition.

Cannot get a numeric value from a error formula cell. because your trying to get the numeric value of Err:522

im using grails 2.4.5 and i have a function to conver the cell value.

```
def getCellValue(Cell cell){
    def result
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            // if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR){
            //  result = 0
            // } else {
            //  result = cell.getNumericCellValue()
            // }
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////

            result = cell.getNumericCellValue()//i need a condition for this case

            break
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            result = cell.getNumericCellValue()
            break
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            result = cell.getStringCellValue()
            break
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            result = cell.getBooleanCellValue()
            break
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            result = null
            break
        default:
            result = cell.toString()
            break
    }

    return result
}
```

the first case is causing an error. i tried using the CELL_TYPE_ERROR in if statement and even one of the case but it doesnt work because the cell type is formula. i even try checking if cell a number but of course its not a number because if you dont use getNumericCellValue() it will retrieve the formula string

i hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Why not use https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCachedFormulaResultType() to check the type of the formula cell and fetch based on that?

Comment: i just tried and i cant use getCachedFormulaResultTypeEnum. i can only use getCachedFormulaResultType but it only returns 0. im using apache poi 3.9